# can't run griffon app

Tags: java, groovy, griffon

I am trying to run a test app in griffon.  I can create the app, but when I go to run it I get the following error(s):

```
2013-01-25 11:12:02,352 [main] INFO  griffon.swing.SwingApplication - Initializing all startup groups: [test1]
2013-01-25 11:12:05,702 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder - An error occurred while building test1.Test1View@63935d75
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create component for 'application' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:97)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:168)
        at test1.Test1View.run(Test1View.groovy:11)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:152)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:160)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at griffon.swing.SwingUtils.createApplicationFrame(SwingUtils.java:133)
        at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.createApplicationContainer(AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.java:99)
        at griffon.core.GriffonApplication$createApplicationContainer.call(Unknown Source)
        at griffon.swing.factory.ApplicationFactory.newInstance(ApplicationFactory.groovy:54)
        ... 8 more
2013-01-25 11:12:05,714 [main] ERROR griffon.util.GriffonExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create component for 'application' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:97)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:168)
        at test1.Test1View.run(Test1View.groovy:11)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:152)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:160)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at griffon.swing.SwingUtils.createApplicationFrame(SwingUtils.java:133)
        at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.createApplicationContainer(AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.java:99)
        at griffon.core.GriffonApplication$createApplicationContainer.call(Unknown Source)
        at griffon.swing.factory.ApplicationFactory.newInstance(ApplicationFactory.groovy:54)
        ... 8 more
```

Any insight you can give would be great.
My set up is:

Kubuntu Linux 12.10 64-bit

```
------------------------------------------------------------
  Griffon 1.2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

   Build: 11-Jan-2013 09:10 AM
  Groovy: 2.0.6
     Ant: 1.8.4
   Slf4j: 1.7.2
  Spring: 3.2.0.RELEASE
     JVM: 1.7.0_09 (Oracle Corporation 23.2-b09)
      OS: Linux 3.5.0-22-generic amd64
```

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: The exception (HeadlessException) seems related to a java parameter (`-java.awt.headless`): https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/how_to_resolve_java_exceptions_java_awt_headlessexception7?lang=en

Comment: how to set this parameter is my question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!
I needed to have the JRE installed and I didn't.  It was looking for a dependency that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionioned in the docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html , this should be a problem with keyboard, mouse or display.

Assuming you did not force "-Djava.awt.headless=true", this is most likely caused by a missing connection to a X-server.

Type

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

in a terminal window. Usually this outputs ":0". Make sure that variable is set (happens automatically for terminal windows), and try starting a very basic X application, such as "xterm". If that works, the griffon app should launch and display.

Comment: set to :0 or :1 and how do I set that??

Comment: from echo display command:    ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/griffon_projects/test1$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

Comment: I typed in konsole after setting the display to DISPLAY=0:0 and got this warning: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.

Comment: I did an echo $MOUSE and echo $KEYBOARD and came up with nothing ... is this correct??